# Prove $2^{(2^n)}+1$ divides $2^{(2^nb)}+1$ for $n,b\in \mathbb{N}$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility

I'm trying to prove $2^{(2^n)}+1$ divides $2^{(2^nb)}+1$ for $n,b\in \mathbb{N}$. I've considered factoring $2^{(2^n)}+1$ into $(2+1)(2^{(2^n)-1}-2^{(2^n)-2}+...+1)$ and likewise $2^{(2^nb)}+1$ into $(2+1)(2^{(2^nb)-1}-2^{(2^nb)-2}+...+1)$

Proofs follow using the same methods as in the dupe, e.g. $$\bmod 2^{2^n}\!+1\!:\ 2^{2^n}\equiv -1 \Rightarrow (2^{2^n})^b\equiv (-1)^b\equiv -1$$ by the [Congruence Power Rule](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/879262/242). Or, equivalently use the Factor Theorem or other closely related methods mentioned there (and its links).

Comment: This is a dupe of a FAQ ...hold on ...

Comment: It's always true when $b$ is odd because $a+1 \mid a^b+1$ for odd $b$.  But that doesn't quite get you where you need to be.

Comment: I forgot to mention $b$ is odd. I think I might know where to go from there. Thanks.

Comment: Good, because $5=2^2+1 \nmid 2^4+1=17$.

Comment: Proofs follow using the same methods as in the dupe, e.g. $$\large \bmod 2^{2^n}\!+1\!:\,\ \color{#c00}{2^{2^n}\equiv -1} \Rightarrow (\color{#c00}{2^{2^n}})^b\equiv (\color{#c00}{-1})^b\equiv -1\qquad$$ by raising the congruence to power $\,b\,$ via the [Congruence Power Rule](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/879262/242). Or, equivalently, use the Factor Theorem or other closely related methods mentioned there (and its links).